# Sum values according to another column and vice versa

Tags: sql, excel

I'm converting an excel file into a SQL, one of the excel tables has two columns with the following formulas:

- `t2.Col 1` = `SUMIF( [Col 2], [ToDate], "<=" [AuxToDate] )`
- `t2.Col 2` = `[col 3] - [Col 1]`
- `Column 3` is already calculated.
- `Column 2` is the sum of individual rows of `column 1` with `column 3`.
- `Column 1` is the sum of all rows where `ToDate < AuxToDate` of `Column 1`

I previously created the columns `c1` and `c2` with 0 for every value.
The columns `[ToDate]` and `[AuxToDate]` are already calculated.

I tried using the following query:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT

    t1.warehouse,
    CASE WHEN t2.AuxToDateM1 >= t1.[ToDate] THEN SUM(t2.[Col 2]) ELSE 0 END name1,
    col 3 - CASE WHEN t2.AuxToDateM1 >= t1.[ToDate] THEN SUM(t2.[Col 2]) ELSE 0 END name2,

    AuxToDateM1

FROM
    t1
    LEFT JOIN [t2] on
        t2.Warehouse = t1.Warehouse
        AND
        t1.FromDate = t2.FromDate
        AND
        t1.ToDate = t2.ToDate
```

Some of the values for `col 2` are correct but `col 1` doesn't calculate anything and only gives me zeros.

Do you have any idea on how to accomplish this?

Sorry If I didn't explain myself very well and I tried searching for this beforehand but didn't find anything.

Comment: Please make a SQLFiddle or DBFiddle with sample data.

Comment: I'll have to look at using square brackets in an Excel function.  I don't think I've ever seen that.